# Displaying Toast after opening a Settings Activity

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, android-toast

I'm trying to display a Toast right after I open a Settings Activity, which should contain a few instructions on what to do in the opening screen.

For example, let's say I want the user to connect to a specific network, so in my code I run

```kt
    Toast.makeText(context, "Instruction message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    startActivity(Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS))
```

to display a Toast followed by a call to open up the WiFi Settings Activity.  The problem here is that the Toast will display in the current Activity inside my app, but very quickly disappear as soon as the new Activity comes up.

I'm wondering if there's a way of displaying that same Toast but on the opening Activity, rather than the one that is doing the call, in order to properly instruct the user on what to do on such new Activity.

Or perhaps there's a better way of achieving this?

Comment: What happens with your activity after you call that, does it close? LENGHT_SHORT is 2s. I would need to test this but I don't think toasts disappear after switching activity. Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS is a string, startActivity takes an Intent, does this work?

Comment: Toasts for showing instructions are highly discouraged. A toast is for showing quick messages with just a few words to let you know something has happened. They disappear very quickly. You might consider this library instead. https://github.com/skydoves/Balloon

Comment: @IamFr0ssT sorry it was a typo having Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS on its own. I've updated the question and the full line now reads `startActivity(Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS))`.

I should also add that the Toast is disappearing before it's time, I believe because we're leaving the context from which it is called.

Comment: Valid point @Tenfour04 that Toast are not meant to show instructions -- it does feel weird trying to do this initially to me too, but I wasn't sure how to convey the message. And even though this Ballon lib looks very interesting and fun, I don't think I'm looking to implement anything for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be better if you used a dialog, so after clicking OK, the user will be shown the screen to change WiFi, like so:

```
AlertDialog.Builder(context)
    .setTitle("Your app name")
    .setMessage("Please turn on WiFi on the following screen.")
    .setPositiveButton("OK", DialogInterface.OnClickListener { dialog, id ->
        {
            startActivity(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS)
        }
    })
    .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
    .show();
```

You can read more about Dialogs here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs

Comment: I guess this is not a bad idea, especially from the user perspective.

I don't, however, think this is answering my original question, which is to know if there's a way of displaying a Toast in the context of the Activity to come.